# Class events bind and unbind

Tags: javascript, class, events, bind, addeventlistener

Everyhing works fine, except I can't figure out how to unbind the events in `stop()`.

### Code updated

```js
class Resizable {
  go(drag_el, resize_el) {
    this.resize_el = resize_el;

    drag_el.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
      window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.resize.bind(this));
      window.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
        window.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.resize.bind(this));
        window.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.resize.bind(this));
      });
    });
  }

  resize(e) {
    this.resize_el.style.width = e.clientX - this.resize_el.offsetLeft + "px";
  }
}
```

### A few notes

- I prefer to keep the class things inside the class, no additional `var` outside it.
- I accept ES5 and ES6 as well.
- I've read that I could do `window.mousemove.bind(() => { // Code });` but I don't get that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove listeners inside `stop` function because you don't know them references.

`Mousemove` event don't call `resize` function, it call anonymous function

```
e => {
  this.resize(resize_el, e);
}
```

You can save address of anonymous function in variable and use it for removing listener, like this

```
class Resizable {
  constructor() {
    this.mouseMoveHandler = (e) => {
      this.resize(resize_el, e);
    };

    this.mouseDownHandler = () => {
      window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.mouseMoveHandler);
    }

    this.mouseUpHandler = () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.mouseMoveHandler);
    }
  }

  go(drag_el, resize_el) {
    drag_el.addEventListener("mousedown", this.mouseDownHandler);

    window.addEventListener("mouseup", this.mouseUpHandler);
  }

  resize(resize_el, e) {
    resize_el.style.width = e.clientX - resize_el.offsetLeft + "px";
  }

  stop() {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.mouseMoveHandler); // ?
    // most likely you would like remove listeners from this.go
  }
}
```

You can find more info in [this article on Medium [removeEventListener() and anonymous function]](https://medium.com/@DavideRama/removeeventlistener-and-anonymous-functions-ab9dbabd3e7b)

**UPD (after question update)**:

.bind() create NEW function everytime, so you still can't remove event listener.

Check my fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/nvfcq80z/5/

Comment: That does not work because I need to pass a param. For that I needed bind. I've updated my code. It does still not work.

Comment: @JensTörnell I prepare fiddle, you can check it https://jsfiddle.net/nvfcq80z/5/

Comment: I tested it and it works great. One thing I noticed is that the `stop()` method is no longer needed. https://jsfiddle.net/gkvnxL9b/

Comment: It was really hard to pick a winner, but you won the accepted answer. As a complement, I've combined your solution and another good solution into an own answer in case you are interesting of the final result. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59069272/148496

Answer (score 2):

For scenario as such, I usually prefer pass the object directly as listener to `addEventListener`: it makes everything easier IMVHO. You have just to implement the [handleEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener/handleEvent) method:

```
class Resizable {
  // Keeping a reference to the elements it's easier for the events handling
  constructor(drag_el, resize_el) {
    this.drag_el = drag_el;
    this.resize_el = resize_el;
    // The entry point event handler is added in the constructor
    // to avoid to add multiple listeners (e.g. in the original
    // code we could have called `go` method multiple times).
    this.drag_el.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
      // Here we add the object itself as event handler
      window.addEventListener("mousemove", this);
      window.addEventListener("mouseup", this);
    });
  }

  resize(e) {
    this.resize_el.style.width = e.clientX - this.resize_el.offsetLeft + "px";
  }

  // Here we're removing the object itself as event handler
  stop() {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", this, false);
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", this, false);
  }

  // Here we're handling the events: since we added the object
  // itself, `this` is still pointing to our instance of `Resizable`
  // so we can call its methods.
  handleEvent(event) {
    switch (event.type) {
        case "mousemove": 
          this.resize(event);
          break;
        case "mouseup":
          this.stop();
          break;
    }
  }
}
```

This approach reduces the usage of bindings and arrow functions a lot.

Here you can find a [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/zer0/pen/bGGPKvG) with this code running.

Comment: Your codepen seems to work as expected. It also looks very much like what I'm trying to build. Will test it out more tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: I had two great answers, yours and another one. I choose the other one, but it was really hard to pick the best one. I've combined your solution and the winner solution into an own answer in case you are interesting of the final result. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59069272/148496

Answer (score 1):

somehow what saveli said is true you have to call same function reference(pointing to same function called inside the listener) when removing listener ,if you wanna far more explaining ask sure you can ask

```
class Resizable {
   go(drag_el, resize_el) {
      this.resize_el=resize_el;
      drag_el.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
         $(window).bind("mousemove", this.resize);
         $(window).bind("mouseup", this.stop);
      });
   }

   resize= (e) =>{
         this.resize_el.style.width = e.clientX - this.resize_el.offsetLeft + "px";;
    }
   stop =(event) =>{
                $(window).unbind(event,this.stop);
                $(window).unbind("mousemove",this.resize); 
    }

}
```

---

edit this one with js only no jquery

```
class Resizable {
   go(drag_el, resize_el) {
      this.resize_el=resize_el;
      drag_el.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
         window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.resize);
         window.addEventListener("mouseup", this.stop);
      });
   }

   resize= (e) =>{
         this.resize_el.style.width = e.clientX - this.resize_el.offsetLeft + "px";
   }
  stop =(event) =>{ 
      window.removeEventListener(event,this.stop);
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove",this.resize);
   }

}
```

Comment: That looks like jQuery, I use Javascript.

Comment: now you have both one with jquery other one js only

Comment: It did not, but I have two other answers that does work. Thanks anyway for your efforts.

Comment: i tested it but ok

Answer (score 1):

I have already accepted the working answer that I liked the most. However I think a combination of @SaveliTomac and @ZER0 would be the best answer.

Therefor I have picked the best from both worlds, at least in my opinion.

https://jsfiddle.net/nhLjozm7/

#### HTML

```html
<aside class="sidebar1">
  <div class="sidebar1-resize"></div>
</aside>

<div class="sidebar2">
  <div class="sidebar2-resize"></div>
</div>
```

#### JS

```js
class Resizable {
  constructor(drag_el, resize_el) {
    this.drag_el = drag_el;
    this.resize_el = resize_el;

    this.handlers();
    this.events();
  }

  handlers() {
    this.mouseMoveHandler = (e) => {
      this.resize(this.resize_el, e);
    };

    this.mouseDownHandler = () => {
      window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.mouseMoveHandler);
    }

    this.mouseUpHandler = () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.mouseMoveHandler);
    }
  }

  events() {
    this.drag_el.addEventListener("mousedown", this.mouseDownHandler);
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", this.mouseUpHandler);
  }

  resize(resize_el, e) {
    resize_el.style.width = e.clientX - resize_el.offsetLeft + "px";
  }
}

let drag1 = document.querySelector(".sidebar1-resize");
let element1 = document.querySelector(".sidebar1");
new Resizable(drag1, element1);

let drag2 = document.querySelector(".sidebar2-resize");
let element2 = document.querySelector(".sidebar2");
new Resizable(drag2, element2);
```

- I like the more flat handlers structure by @SaveliTomac (no nesting of events).
- I like how @ZER0 put the resize handle inside the aside instead of outside of it.
- I like how both @ZER0 and @SaveliTomac solutions support multiple resizable areas.
- I like the clean and readability code by @SaveliTomac.
- I like the set of values directly into constructor by @ZER0.
- I wrapped all handlers into a method.
- I wrapped events into a method.
- I changed the HTML a bit.
- I show two resizable elements.

Comment: In truth you would like unsubscribe from mousedown on drag_el and mouseup on window, because it may cause memory leaks. I prepared fiddle again :) https://jsfiddle.net/cqpux9yg/ You can run code and click on result page, after check your console